# Why is my for loop treating each column as a separate line?

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk

I have a text file with this two column structure:

```
$ head sigScaf.txt
scaffold4471 1404
scaffold4514 61
scaffold4514 100
scaffold4514 312
scaffold4514 313
scaffold6052 12989
scaffold25893 980
scaffold31460 67
scaffold54069 553
scaffold54660 7705
```

I want to write a loop that generates two files, one containing the contents of the first column (scaffold number) and the other containing the contents of the second column (integer), and then print the content of those files for each loop.

The script I have written looks like this:

```
$ cat test.sh

#!/bin/bash

for i in $(cat sigScaf.txt)
do

echo $i >sig.tmp

awk '{print $1}' sig.tmp >scaf.tmp
awk '{print $2}' sig.tmp >pos.tmp

echo "Scaffold:"
cat scaf.tmp

echo "Position:"
cat pos.tmp

done
```

I assumed the output would look like the following:

```
$ bash test.sh | head
Scaffold: scaffold4471
Position: 1404
Scaffold: scaffold4514
Position: 61
Scaffold: scaffold4514
Position: 100
Scaffold: scaffold4514
Position: 312
Scaffold: scaffold4514
Position: 313
```

However, the output looks like this (with extra lines to properly demonstrate the issue):

```
$ bash test.sh | head -50
Scaffold:
scaffold4471
Position:

Scaffold:
1404
Position:

Scaffold:
scaffold4514
Position:

Scaffold:
61
Position:

Scaffold:
scaffold4514
Position:

Scaffold:
100
Position:

Scaffold:
scaffold4514
Position:

Scaffold:
312
Position:

Scaffold:
scaffold4514
Position:

Scaffold:
313
Position:

Scaffold:
scaffold6052
Position:

Scaffold:
12989
Position:

Scaffold:
scaffold25893
```

It appears that the second column is instead being treated as a new line, making every second line of the loop output the integer to the temporary `scaf.tmp` file and leaving the `pos.tmp` file empty as there appears to be no second column for `awk` to read.

I feel like the solution is right in front of me but I have tried for so long to find the source of the problem that the script has lost all meaning to me.

Does anyone know what might cause this?

Cheers

Comment: Use `read` for this. `while read -r line; do [...contents of loop]... done < sigScaf.txt`. What you've got right now is throwing the contents into a variable, then looping over that variable string, which is space-separated. You can see the same behavior if you do something like `foo="a b c"; for x in $foo; do echo $x; done`

Comment: That is a common mistake, see why you [DRLWF](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: You can also use `read -a` to give yourself an array automatically, removing the need for the awk calls.

Comment: You don't need a loop here. `cut -d ' ' -f 1  sigScaf.txt && cut -d ' ' -f 2  sigScaf.txt` would do as well.

Comment: What I find strange in your code is, that in **every** iteration of your loop, you also create files scaf.tmp and pos.tmp, each iteration overwriting the file of the previous iteration. What's the point in doing it?

Comment: `for i in $(cat sigScaf.txt)` is an anti-pattern (see [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)) and you should not use a shell read loop for this (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)). As the bash tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here"

Comment: Regarding `I want to write a loop that generates two temporary files` - do you really want those 2 files created or is that just what you think you need to get to your final output format? Is the block of text under `I assumed the output...` the output you WANT to get or just what you thought that script would output and your desired output is actually something else?

Comment: @user1934428 that is a good point. I should point out that I have a downstream intent for those temporary files in the same loop, but I ran into the problem I've described where the input is treated as a new line instead of a new column. I identified this as the problem, so I simplified the question by creating an example specific to the problem, rather than the entirety of the script I intend to write. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @EdMorton I do have a higher purpose for the base of this code, which will work when the contents of the temporary files reflect what I outlined in the assumed output section of my question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then, for the purposes of your question, they aren't temporary files, they're the final desired output files from the script you're asking for help to create, and so you should remove that term from your question as it's causing confusion. Also clean up the part starting at `I assumed the output would look like the following:` as that's apparently irrelevant and adding to the confusion since your expected output is simply the 2 separate files.

Comment: Given you just want those 2 separate files output - that's exactly what [@DiegoTorresMilano's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75106744/1745001) does so why haven't you accepted it yet? Is there something else you needed that it doesn't do?

Comment: @EdMorton okay thanks. I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the columns using `awk`

```
awk '{print $1 > "scaf.tmp"; print $2 > "pos.tmp"}' sigScaf.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU `AWK` does have implicit loop, you might use it to get desired output without creating temporary files following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
scaffold4471 1404
scaffold4514 61
scaffold4514 100
scaffold4514 312
scaffold4514 313
scaffold6052 12989
scaffold25893 980
scaffold31460 67
scaffold54069 553
scaffold54660 7705
```

then

```
awk '{printf "Scaffold: %s\nPosition: %s\n",$1,$2}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
Scaffold: scaffold4471
Position: 1404
Scaffold: scaffold4514
Position: 61
Scaffold: scaffold4514
Position: 100
Scaffold: scaffold4514
Position: 312
Scaffold: scaffold4514
Position: 313
Scaffold: scaffold6052
Position: 12989
Scaffold: scaffold25893
Position: 980
Scaffold: scaffold31460
Position: 67
Scaffold: scaffold54069
Position: 553
Scaffold: scaffold54660
Position: 7705
```

Explanation: I use [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Basic-Printf.html) to format and then print string, `%s` denotes place for insertion, `$1` and `$2` are values to insert. Observe that trailing `\n` is required as unlike `print` no `ORS` is added by default.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mawk 'sub(_, "Scaffold: ", $!(NF=NF))' OFS='\nPosition: '
> ```

```
Scaffold: scaffold4471
Position: 1404
Scaffold: scaffold4514
Position: 61
Scaffold: scaffold4514
Position: 100
Scaffold: scaffold4514
Position: 312
Scaffold: scaffold4514
Position: 313
Scaffold: scaffold6052
Position: 12989
Scaffold: scaffold25893
Position: 980
Scaffold: scaffold31460
Position: 67
Scaffold: scaffold54069
Position: 553
Scaffold: scaffold54660
Position: 7705
```